# Orientation (at configChanges) change makes my buttons stop work after orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I have this neat app...

At onCreate, it draws the "startscreen.xml" accordingly to :

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.startscreen);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.window_title);
```

And in my app, i have "configChanges="orientation" " in the manifest.
And i have,

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.startscreen);

}
```

startscreen.xml is both a landscape and portrait-layout, both are separated.

So to the problem, the app loads fine, buttons work. I switch orientation, the button stops responding...

They are both using RelativeLayout...

Any clues, anyone? :S

EDIT:

Tried this now thanks to your comments, but no result :S

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.startscreen);

    add_note.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            createNote();
        }

    });
}
```

Do you mean that onclickListener or these :

```
add_note = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addnote);
```

?? :S

Comment: Where are you registering your onClickListeners?

Comment: @DreamHawk: If you switch orientation back to the original do the buttons start working again?

Comment: @Squonk, no they dont :/, i have to close and reopen :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349531/one-of-my-apps-button-becomes-unclickable-after-device-rotation need help on my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are adding click listeners in `onCreate` to your buttons, you need to add listeners to the new button objects created in `onConfigurationChanged`.

You might consider using the `android:onClick` attribute in your XML files instead of setting click listeners in code. That's a nice way of avoiding this problem.

To use `android:onClick` from XML, do something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addnote"
    android:onClick="addNoteMethod"
    ....
    />
```

Then in your activity, define the method:

```
public void addNoteMethod(View view) {
    createNote();
}
```

The name of the `android:onClick` method is totally arbitrary; it just has to match a method in your activity with the proper signature (`void <method_name>(View)`). The method will be called when there's a click in exactly the same manner that the `onClick` method would be called for an `OnClickListener`.

When using `android:onClick`, you do *not* need to call `setOnClickListener` (or even retrieve a reference to the button in `onCreate`, unless you need it for something else).

Comment: Check my edit, how do i, in that case, start a function like createNote, from xml-android:onClick?

Comment: @DreamHawk - responding to your question update: you'll have to call `findViewById` again to set `add_note` to the new button instance (the old one is gone), and also call `add_note.setOnClickListener`. I'll update my answer to show how to use `android:onClick` from XML.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - OP said that `configChanges="orientation"` is in the manifest. The activity is not destroyed and re-created in that circumstance.

Comment: @Ted: Sorry, just spotted that - my bad. Not enough coffee yet.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - no worries :)

Comment: Thank you Ted Hopp, i changed all my "Onclicklisteners" to android:onClick, which made them work from any orientation!